# How to call a custom taxonomy term name inside a function?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions, terms

With the following [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090698/wordpress-include-content-of-one-page-in-another), the content of another page is included into a page template, which is working fine:

```
// add content of another page
function show_post($path) {
  $post = get_page_by_path($path);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
  echo $content;
}
```

The function is called like this:

Now I placed this code inside a custom taxonomy template:

- taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php

Is there a possibility, to give the $term-name automatically in this function, without hard-coding it?

For example, the custom taxonomy template is taxonomy-cars-mercedes.php, I want the function doing this:

```
<?php 
show_post('mercedes');  // Shows the content of the "About" page. 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current term slug from the global query. You could do something like this:

```
if( is_tax('cars') ) {
    //We are in "cars" taxonomy archive page, now get the queried term
    $term = get_query_var( 'term' );
    show_post($term);
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. If it answer your question please, mark the answer as accepted.